# How to store the value into array every time the user click on next button in xcode?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

When the user click the next button, it generate random number and I would like to store the number into the array. My array is storing the last number only. Should I initialize the array outside the 'next' function?
Moreover, I would like the 'back button' to read the array from the last in number.
Please advise.

```
- (IBAction)Next:(id)sender {

    //generate random number - result is a range of 0-10   
    int randomnumber = (arc4random() % 9);

    //hold the array number up to 10

    NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10]; 

    // insert the random number into array

    [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomnumber]];

    // when I see in debug mode, my array only storing the last number  

    NSLog([myArray description]);

}

- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender {

   //I miss a lot of code in this part

    NSNumber *last_array_num = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: yes you should initilize the array outside, so it will keep on adding new elements in same array, rather then creating new one each time. also it will make you access that array in other methods as well.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the function next called the NSMutable array is declared again and again... so try declare the NSMutable array outside the next function

Comment: Outside being inside the corresponding `@interface` block, thus declaring an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize array as a class variable.

Comment: As an instance variable, not a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

the randomnumber will be in the 0-8 range since it can't be grater than 9 cause that wouldn't be module of it.

Also your problem is you're creating a new array each time

You should create it outside and use a instance variable.

```
- (id)init {
     myArray =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
     [super init];
 }
```

define in your header file the myArray as a Mutable Array

Comment: An instance variable, not a global (class) variable. Also, subclasses are supposed to invoke the superclass’ designated initialiser.

Comment: i'm sorry for that misconcept. 
and really? to do [super init] is not part of the issue in hand, but ok, i'll fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (void) initArray
{
   //hold the array number up to 10
   myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];
}

- (IBAction)Next:(id)sender {

    //generate random number - result is a range of 0-10   
    int randomnumber = (arc4random() % 9);

    // insert the random number into array

    [myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:randomnumber]];

    // when I see in debug mode, my array only storing the last number  

    NSLog([myArray description]);

}

- (IBAction)Back:(id)sender {

   //I miss a lot of code in this part

    NSNumber *last_array_num = [myArray objectAtIndex:[myArray.count - 1]];
}
```